# Bootstrap modal not closing after ajax form submit

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a modal that submits courses registered by students. After successful submission, the modal closes but it leaves a faded background. I have tried possible solutions seen here on StackOverflow but none is working for me. I know this question is a duplicate of another, but it paints a different scenario.

**This is my modal form**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="regModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="z-index:10000;">

   <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;text-align:center;">Course Registration</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="#" style="" id="form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <div class="container-fluid-div" style="">
                        <div class="row-div" style="">
                            
                            <div class="colx9" style="">
                            <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT CourseCode, CourseTitle FROM admintbl WHERE Level = ? EXCEPT SELECT CourseCode, CourseTitle FROM cregtbl WHERE Level = ? AND RegNo = ?";
                                    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
                                    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $pLevel1, $pLevel2, $pregno);
                                    $pLevel1 = $_SESSION['level'];
                                    $pLevel2 = $_SESSION['level'];
                                    $pregno = $_SESSION['regno'];
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                                    if ($num_rows > 0){
                                        $cbIndex = 1;
                                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                            $c_code = $row['CourseCode'];
                                            $c_title = $row['CourseTitle'];
                                            ?>
                                            <label class="chkLabel" style=""> <?php echo $cbIndex;?>. <?php echo $c_code;?> - <?php echo $c_title;?> <input style="" type="checkbox" class="inChk" name="inChk[]" id="inChk" value="<?php echo $c_code;?>"></input></label>
                                            <?php
                                            $cbIndex++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo "<p style='color:darkblue;'>Oops! Seems you've registered all courses. No more courses available.</p>";
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        <div style="width:100%;margin:0;margin-top:10px;text-align:right;">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="width:100%;" value="" >Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:left;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" style="float:left;background:lightgrey;color:#000;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My ajax submit**

```
<!--AJAX PROCESS TO SUBMIT CHECKED COURSES-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadNewCourse();
        loadDelTable();

        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $("#form").submit(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'cos_reg.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data){
                        loadNewCourse();
                        loadDelTable();
                        $( '#regModal' ).modal('hide');
                        swal({
                            // "Success", "Registration successful", "success"
                            position: "top-end",
                            type: "success",
                            title: "Registration successful",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        swal("Oops...", "Registration failed.", "error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
       function loadNewCourse(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'processReg.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: {
                    loadit: 1
                },
                success: function(disp){
                    $("#reveal").html(disp).show();
                }
            });
        }
        
        function loadDelTable(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete_tbl.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: {
                    loadDel: 1
                },
                success: function(deldisp){
                    $("#showRegtbl").html(deldisp).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**My HTML here**

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="animated fadeInLef" style="margin-bottom:5%;width:100%">
        <div style="background:#273640;width:100%;margin-top:px;padding:0.5rem;"><center>
            <a class="regh4" style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0px;width:auto;text-decoration:none;"><h5 class="#" style="font-family: 'proxima-nova','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:5px;color:#fff;margin-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i> Course Registration Form</h5></a>
        </center></div><br>
           <!--Display Courses that are available-->
             <span id="reveal"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: $( '#regModal' ).modal('hide'); replace this with this  $('#regModal').modal('hide'); and it will work.

Comment: What's the difference between $( '#regModal' ).modal('hide'); and  $('#regModal').modal('hide'); @Neeraj

Comment: space after and before bracket you have to remove it

Comment: It still doesn't work, I've removed the spaces.
The ajax submits successfully, the modal closes but leaves a faded background like blur. I have to refresh page before it goes off.

Comment: as i can check it's hide properly without any issue.

Comment: loadNewCourse(); loadDelTable(); comment this two line check may be issue in these two function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem for me. Thanks guys.

```
$('body').removeAttr('style');
$('#regModal').removeAttr('style');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the PHP and Ajax part of your code and open menu on show button and hide in or submit form it's working perfectly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $("#form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#regModal').modal('hide');
        })

    });
    $('#regModal').modal('hide');
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $('#regModal').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="show">show</button>
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="animated fadeInLef" style="margin-bottom:5%;width:100%">
        <div style="background:#273640;width:100%;margin-top:px;padding:0.5rem;"><center>
            <a class="regh4" style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0px;width:auto;text-decoration:none;"><h5 class="#" style="font-family: 'proxima-nova','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:5px;color:#fff;margin-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i> Course Registration Form</h5></a>
        </center></div><br>
           <!--Display Courses that are available-->
             <span id="reveal"></span>
<div class="modal fade" id="regModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="z-index:10000;">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 style="margin-bottom:0;text-align:center;">Course Registration</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="#" style="" id="form" method="POST" action="#">
                    <div class="container-fluid-div" style="">
                        <div class="row-div" style="">

                            </div>
                        <div style="width:100%;margin:0;margin-top:10px;text-align:right;">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="width:100%;" value="" >Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:left;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" style="float:left;background:lightgrey;color:#000;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works fine. I even tried that too. But once I include the ajax, after the successful submit, the modal goes away but the faded background still shows. I just can't figure out what I'm not doing right.